# Calculate $\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{|e^h-1-k|(e^h-1)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a task in which I get $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{|e^h-1-k|(e^h-1)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

I've been trying for a long time, but I don't know how to prove that the limit is equal to $0$.

I tried to use the comparison criterion:
$$\frac{\left|e^h-1-k\right|\left(e^h-1\right)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\le\frac{e^h-1}{h}\cdot \frac{h|e^h-1-k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\le \frac{e^h-1}{h}\cdot \left( \frac{h|e^h-1|}{|h|}+\frac{h|k|}{|k|} \right) $$
and:
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{e^h-1}{h}\cdot\left( \frac{h\left|e^h-1\right|}{|h|}+\frac{h|k|}{|k|} \right) =\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}1\cdot(h\cdot 1+h)=0$$
But I don't have idea to the limit on the left.Since the expression is not always positive, it is not a trivial case to write $0\le \dots$

Comment: You should show our work and effort on that

Comment: *Your work and effort on that

Comment: approaching $(0,0)$ along any of the lines $k=mh$ ...

$$|L|=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|e^h-1-mh|\times |e^h-1|}{|h|\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
You can use the fact that ...
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ e^h-1}{h}=1$$

Comment: @WW1 The limit along your lines is not sufficient to prove that $\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}$ exists (along *any curve*).

Comment: If you show your work on that, we can give a complete answer with our suggestions.

Comment: @WW1 You should delete your comment which is totally wrong, as already noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost done! Just put absolute value signs everywhere:
$$\begin{align}\frac{|e^h-1-k||e^h-1|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}&\le\left|\frac{e^h-1}h\right|\frac{|h||e^h-1-k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\&\le\left|\frac{e^h-1}h\right|\left( \frac{|h||e^h-1|}{|h|}+\frac{|h||k|}{|k|}\right)\\&=\left|\frac{e^h-1}h\right|\left(|e^h-1|+|h|\right)\end{align}$$
and
$$\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{e^h-1}h\right|\left(|e^h-1|+|h|\right)=1\cdot(0+0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Following your way, we can just take absolute value to conclude

$$0\le \left|\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right|\cdot \frac{|h||e^h-1-k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\le \left|\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right|\cdot \left( \frac{|h||e^h-1|}{|h|}+\frac{|h||k|}{|k|} \right) \to 0$$

and use that $|f(x)|\to 0 \iff f(x)\to 0$.

As an alternative have that

$$\frac{|e^h-1-k|(e^h-1)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = \frac{e^h-1}{h}  \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}|e^h-1-k|$$

with

- $\frac{e^h-1}{h}\to 1$
- $-1\le \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\le 1$
- $|e^h-1-k|\to 0$

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree indeed at first I've asked for some context, then I've seen that you have provided a very strong hint by comments, then I thought you have reconsidered the question deserving some attention. Sorry for that, maybe I've misunderstood your intentions.